# "Give a hand" vs "Help"

Tags: usage

Currently, I'm working in an international company with many non-native speakers (so am I) but with pretty good level of English, I suppose.

I have noticed that my colleagues usually use phrase "give a hand" when asking for  help or even talking about it and seems to be avoiding the strong word "help".

It looks a bit confusing to me especially after I made people laugh when I said  "I will help you" in one of our conversations, don't remember exact context though...

So could you please describe the difference between them? And is there something wrong or hidden meaning with help-based phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following [extract](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+hand), the first & last items are from American sources, and the middle one is from a British source.

[image: 'give somebody a hand']

The first two items support the fact that *to give somebody a hand* is used to mean "to help someone". The third item confirms that (especially in US usage), that may also be expressed as "*to lend somebody a hand*"; although less common, that usage is certainly not unknown — and would certainly be understood — in the UK.

Conversely, if one were *asking* for help, one might say "*Would you please give me a hand with this?*". The expression would certainly be "*give **me** a hand*", but the "me" might be partially 'swallowed' and not heard clearly.

If offering help, I might say "*Do you **want a hand** with that?*". It's easy to see that a non-native speaker may get confused between "*give **me** a hand*" and "*Do **you** want a hand*?".

(As an aside, the usage of *give a **big** hand to someone* (note the word "*big*" in the middle) to mean "give a round of applause" is also common in the UK.)

Finally, although the expression "*I will help you*" may be slightly non-idiomatic, I cannot think that by itself it should be so strange as to make people laugh; but it's possible that it might sound funny in the context of something said previously.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a request for help is usually phrased: **"** ***Lend*** **a hand"**. 
(In other words - "I only have two hands - which is currently an insufficient number - could you lend me one of yours?)

If you found yourself in the midst of an overwhelming task and requested a bystander to *"give (you) a hand,"* you would likely be the recipient of a round of applause. (US)

Comment: in BrEng (and perhaps other variations), "to give someone a hand" **does** mean to help them, rather than applaud them.  (in BrEng you'd say "give him a round of applause" for that).  You would say "Give me a hand", "give him a hand", or "Let me give you a hand", etc, though, rather than just *"give a hand"* with no subject.  "give a hand" seems like a blend between "give me a hand" and "lend a hand".

Comment: Company is based in Amsterdam and has a lot of native speakers from UK

Comment: @klappvisor do they definitely say "give a hand" rather than "give me a hand", "give him a hand" etc?

Comment: Just to confirm the comments from @MaxWilliams, if I (as a Brit) wanted to ask someone casually to help me with a task, it would be quite natural to say, for example, "Would you please give me a hand with this?".  It would be "give *me* a hand", but the "me" might be partially 'swallowed' and not heard clearly.

Comment: @MaxWilliams not quite sure, but probably non natives make mistake and omit pronoun... natives sometimes may use "gime" I guess, which is not very clearly heard as TrevorD metioned

Comment: Following my previous comment, conversely, if I were offering help to someone else, I might say "Do you *want a hand* with that?". It's easy to see that a non-native speaker may get confused between "give *me* a hand" and "Do *you want a hand*?".

Comment: If your colleagues really are avoiding help-based phrases, it could be that they associate asking for help with confessing inadequacy.  "Could you help me with this" makes it clear that you are in some degree of difficulty.  "Could you give me a hand with this" sounds as though you could manage OK by yourself, but it would be nice if you didn't have to.   Possibly the laughter when you said "I will help you" was [nervous laughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervous_laughter) because you revealed something about the culture of your workplace.